# Export results to Excel within script

Tags: sql, excel, export

Is it possible to export the results of a query (a select statement with multiple joins) to an Excel spreadsheet without having to manually export the data, so the script runs the query and also executes the transfer to Excel?

Comment: Which RDBMS? Is there any data manipulation involved or is it pure reading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in SQL*Plus and Oracle SQL Developer.

Create a .sql file. (Create a text file and change the extension to .sql)

Put the following code in the file:

```
set heading off
spool excel_1.xls
select 
    first_name||chr(9)||last_name 
from 
    employees;
spool off
```

Since I have made use of employees table from HR schema, connect hr schema.
Execute the script file

```
@<filename>.sql
```

you can use any number of columns but each should be separated as shown in above example.

Comment: Thanks, you got me on the right track. i added solution in Question